# ViewWillAppear delegate is not calling in TITokenTableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, subview

I am using TITokenTableViewController and its workinag as a subview. And I call another view controller from this subview. Its working fine. but when I go back from this view controller to TITokenTableViewController (subview) that ViewWillAppear is not working. Therefore I cannot pass value for it. So how I pass a value to TITokenTableViewController this sub view ? . In super view viewwillAppear is working.

Comment: How do you call "another" viewController, just add as subview or present it?

Comment: I created a property for viewcontroller in TITokenTableViewController and asign self to that created property in viewDidLoad (myProperty  = self) then call to new view controller from segue.